# Grab data from text based on key word match

Tags: python

I have a text file with the following content:

```
name1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 
...
...
...

nameN -1 -1 1 1 -1 1
```

Also, I have a function that returns one of the names in the file, randomly. Is there a way to convert the text document into a manageable python data type? Basically, if the function returns name1, I want to grab the integer vector associated to "name1".

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward in Python :

- Split your data in lines.
- For each line, split in cells.
- The first cell is your dict key, the values are the other cells.
- Convert them to int.

Done!

```
data = """name1 -1 -1 -1 1 -1 1 
nameN -1 -1 1 1 -1 1"""

my_dict = {}

for line in data.split("\n"):
    cells = line.split()
    my_dict[cells[0]] = [int(x) for x in cells[1:]]

print my_dict
# {'nameN': [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1], 'name1': [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
print my_dict['name1']
# [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
```

If you want to read a file :

```
my_dict = {}

with open('filename.txt') as data:
    for line in data:
        cells = line.split()
        my_dict[cells[0]] = [int(x) for x in cells[1:]]

print my_dict
# {'nameN': [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1], 'name1': [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]}
print my_dict['name1']
# [-1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1]
```

Comment: Hi Eric. Thank you! I don't understand how to convert the text document in a python data type. I come from C environment, and I can't understand how you can have a matrix with strings and integers all together.

Comment: @AMayer: Python is dynamic. Just take a deep breath and accept that it's okay to have a list with different objects : `['1', 2, [3], {4:5}]`. Everything will be fine ;) For this answer, the output is a dict. Keys are strings, values are integer lists.

Comment: I see. But I couldn't manage to open the text file so that I can use the method. For example, if I use with open(fname) as f:
    content = f.readlines(), I get list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Answer (score 0):

Rough outline:

- Iterate over lines in file
- Split the each line (default character is space)
- Check to see if name matches
- If so, build the output by converting each of the remaining elements to the desired integer type.

With that, you'd probably end up with something like this:

```
def getData(name, file)
    for line in file:
        line = line.split()

        if line[0] == name:         
            data = [int(entry) for entry in line[1:]]
            return data
```